# Using HTML form value to search an array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms, object

I have a possibly stupid question about Javascript. I'm not familiar with JS at all and this is causing me massive headache.

What I'm trying to do is create a simple user database using a HTML form, which would allow the user to upload a JSON file to use as a database of sorts, and then would allow the user to search from said JSON file. Namely, the Javascript would first display the number of users (i.e. objects in the array), then the user would be able to check whether a certain user would be in the database. This would be achieved by typing the name in a form which would then return either true or false. Following this would be a more detailed search tool. I've written the form in its entirety in HTML but how to actually do it in JS is beyond me.

What I have so far is the file upload and counting the objects, which works. The second step, which is the name search, always returns -1 upon loading the page, and I don't know how to make it work upon clicking "submit" next to the name input form.

Here is my code, an absolute mess of things I've tried with no success (so sorry in advance if your eyes burn):

index.html (+JS)

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Database for Facebook</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Palanquin+Dark|Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<h1>Database for Facebook</h1>

<h3>Upload a JSON file:</h3>
<input type="file" id="jsonUp">

<h3>Number of users: <b id="nOfUsers"></b></h3>

<h3>Check if user exists:</h3>
<form id="namesearch">
<input type="text" id="nameIn" name="user" placeholder="eg. Rose Tyler"><button type="submit" onclick="containsPerson()">Submit</button><b id="userExists"></b><br>
<sub><b>Note:</b> Returns true if user exists in the database, false if it doesn't</sub>
    </form>

<hr>

<h2>Search for users:</h2>
<form>
    <b>Name:</b><br>
    <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="eg. Donna Noble"><br><br>
    <b>Gender:</b><br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
    <br>
    <b>Music:</b><br>
    <input type="text" name="music" placeholder="eg. The Cure"><br>
    <b>TV Show:</b><br>
    <input type="text" name="tv" placeholder="eg. Twin Peaks"><br>
    <b>Movie:</b><br>
    <input type="text" name="movie" placeholder="eg. Star Wars"><br>
    <b>Restaurant:</b><br>
    <input type="text" name="food" placeholder="eg. Pizza Planet"><br><br>
    <button type="submit"><b>Search</b></button>
</form>

<script type="defiant/xsl-template">

</script>


<script>

    (function() {

        var users = '';
        var nameInput = '';


        // JSON UPLOAD

        function onChange(event) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = onReaderLoad;
            reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
        }

        function onReaderLoad(event) {
            var users = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
            console.log(users);

            // NUMBER OF USERS (OBJECTS)
            document.getElementById('nOfUsers').innerHTML = Object.keys(users).length;

            // NAME SEARCH (true/false)
            function containsPerson(key, users) {

                /*
                var i;

                for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                    if (users[i] && users[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        return users[i][key];
                    }
                }

                return -1;

                */



            }

        userSearch = document.getElementById('nameIn');
        console.log(containsPerson(userSearch, users));

        }

        document.getElementById('jsonUp').addEventListener('change', onChange);


        // ADVANCED SEARCH
        function search() {

        }

    }());

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

I use a file named users.json as the database, and it looks something like this:

```
[
{
    "name": "Rose Tyler",
    "gender": "female",
    "music": ["The Cure", "Radiohead"],
    "tv": ["Futurama"],
    "movies": ["Back to the Future", "Tron"]
},
{
    "name": "Amy Pond",
    "gender": "female",
    "music": ["Pet Shop Boys"],
    "tv": ["Star Trek the Next Generation"],
    "movies": ["Star Wars"],
    "restaurants": ["Bar Britannia"]
},
{
    "name": "Jack Harkness",
    "gender": "male",
    "music": ["Elvis", "Sex Pistols"],
    "tv": ["Wallander", "House of Cards", "Dallas"],
    "movies": ["Amelie"],
    "restaurants": ["Cafe Base", "Duffo", "Gil Abbiano"]
}
]
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have scoped your functions in an another function, `containsPerson()` will not be visible to your search form´s onlick event. Its maybe better to hook up the submit event of the search form from javascript. Example below.

```js
(function () {

    var users = null;
    var nameInput = '';

    // JSON UPLOAD
    function onChange(event) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = onReaderLoad;
        reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
    }

    function onReaderLoad(event) {
        users = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
        //console.log(users);
        document.getElementById('nOfUsers').innerHTML = users.length;
    }

    // NAME SEARCH (true/false)
    function containsPerson() {
        if(!users){
            return -1;
        }
        userSearch = document.getElementById('nameIn').value;
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if (users[i].name === userSearch) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    var form = document.getElementById('namesearch');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('userExists').innerHTML = containsPerson();
    });
    document.getElementById('jsonUp').addEventListener('change', onChange);
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Database for Facebook</title>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Database for Facebook</h1>

<h3>Upload a JSON file:</h3>
<input type="file" id="jsonUp">

<h3>Number of users: <b id="nOfUsers"></b></h3>

<h3>Check if user exists: <b id="userExists"></b></h3>
<form id="namesearch">
<input type="text" id="nameIn" name="user" placeholder="eg. Rose Tyler">
<input type="submit">
<br/>
<sub><b>Note:</b> Returns true if user exists in the database, false if it doesn't</sub>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so very much! Would the detailed search function be built in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why your function always return -1 is because you set it to return -1.

```
function containsPerson(key, users) {   

          var i;

                for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                    if (users[i] && users[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        return users[i][key];
                    }
                }
           // loops end here and the function returns -1


                return -1;                 
            }
```

If you want it to return something else you need to create an if else statement based on what does your loop return.

First return inside the loop only ends the loop and goes "out" to your containsPerson() which is set to return -1.

You'd have to pass to the main/parent function return statement a variable which is the result of the loop or -1, so you could create an if else statement which return:

- -1 if loop is false,
- users[i]key if loop finds something